# Outlook VSTO 2013 Add-In ShowPane() problems

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I have these two following methods:

```
public void ShowCustomPane()
{
    var o = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlPane.olPreview;
    this.Application.ActiveExplorer().ShowPane(o, false);

    myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
}

public void HideCustomPane()
{
    var o = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlPane.olPreview;
    this.Application.ActiveExplorer().ShowPane(o, true);

    myCustomTaskPane.Visible = false;
}
```

The first shows my custom pane and hides the preview pane, it work as expected. The latter should hide my pane and restore the preview pane, but it only hides my pane.

Why does the call not work? How can I restore the preview pane?